# Error when trying to set a UNIQUE constraint with DEFAULT NULL in H2 database

Tags: null, constraints, unique, h2, default

I would like to create a table with a column with a UNIQUE constraint and DEFAULT NULL, see the annotation_id column in the below code snippet. This works in Postgres but fails in H2 but according to the documentation, it should work (http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition).

Here is the DDL script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE highlights (
   id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   user_ref_id uuid,
   body varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
   annotation_id integer UNIQUE DEFAULT NULL
);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE HIGHLIGHTS2 (
   ID BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   USER_REF_ID UUID,
   BODY VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
   ANNOTATION_ID INTEGER UNIQUE DEFAULT[*] NULL
)"; expected "NOT, NULL, COMMENT, CHECK, REFERENCES, ,, )"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE highlights2 (
   id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   user_ref_id uuid,
   body varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,
   annotation_id integer UNIQUE DEFAULT NULL
) [42001-200] 42001/42001
```

According to this thread here, this should be possible: https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/HrYKGMN2LPQ?pli=1

> H2 already supports NULL in unique constraints.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You cannot specify a column constraint (`UNIQUE` or any other) in the middle of definition of a column, such constraint can be written only at the end of column's definition: `annotation_id integer DEFAULT NULL UNIQUE`.
2. `DEFAULT NULL` is a meaningless clause, all nullable columns will be assigned to `NULL` with or without this clause if other value wasn't specified. This clause can be removed. You need to use the `DEFAULT` clause only when you want to specify some other value as default.

Comment: Thanks Evgenij, the second part of your answer clears this up for me. Regarding the first part though, could you shed a bit more light on why that constraint can't be defined in the middle of the definition? Is it specific to H2? It works in Postgres.

Comment: In the SQL Standard, definition of a column begins with its name immediately followed by data type or domain name; then one of default, identity, generation, etc. clauses may be optionally specified; after it column constraint(s) may be optionally specified; and collation may be optionally specified after them (H2 doesn't support per-column collations). So it isn't H2-specific, it's a general rule. But some DBMS may have own non-portable extensions, you shouldn't rely on them when you use the same SQL in different DBMS.